# Session Variables For Logging in

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have a login page which the user logs in with a username and password, then i want to display if my user is logged in, his name, so i got a login() function to determine if they can login, if it returns true, then it sets up a session variable and then calls function get_logged_on_person() which first the users first and last name from my database, but then i dont know what to do from there on. Any help is appreciated; my login_action.php is as follows:

```
# Get form data
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (login($username, $password) == true) {
    session_start();
    $sessionid = session_id();
    $insession = true;
    $logonas = get_logged_on_person($username);
    $firstname = $logonas.firstname;
    $lastname = $logonas.lastname;
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $lastname;
        ????


}else{
  $error = "Incorrect login.";
  header("Location: login.php?error=$error");
  exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: `$logonas.firstname` is not valid PHP.  What is `$logonas`, an array or an object?

Comment: Yeah, thats what i thought, $logonas is an array.

Comment: You access array keys through `$logonas['firstname']` and `$logonas['lastname']` in PHP.

Comment: ..and I don't understand your question.  You've done everything you need to do.

Comment: Well umm, how do i access the session so i can display there first name and last name at the top of every page, will a simple 'Currently logged in as: $_SESSION['firstname'] or $firstname'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the top of every page, start with (before any output):

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Where you want to display the user information, use:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['firstname']))
    echo "Currently logged in as: {$_SESSION['firstname']}";
else
    echo "Not logged in";
?>
```

Of course, if you already are inside `<?php ... ?>` tags, then omit them.

---

You don't need to do anything more than setting at `...`. You should, however, change your code here:

```
$firstname = $logonas.firstname;
$lastname = $logonas.lastname;
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $lastname;
    ????
```

Replace with:

```
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $logonas['firstname'];
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $logonas['lastname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

After you manage to create session variable $_SESSION['firstname'] you can call it from any page. One thing - Each page must start with session_start(); statement